# How to conditionally apply Angular filters on ng-repeat of object attributes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, conditional-statements, angular-filters

I have an object with 100+ attributes, such as "name", "price", "expiry date"...etc
I am using ng-repeat to iterate through all the key-pair values of the object and displaying them on a table.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in attr_array">
        <td><b>{{x.key}}</b></td>
        <td>{{x.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I want to use the Angular date-filter on certain attributes, such as any date fields:

```
{{ x.value | date: 'MMM d, y'}}
```

And ideally other filters too. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe use `ng-if="x.value instanceof Date"` as an attribute for your td-element. And repeat for every datatype

Comment: Ideally I would like to apply multiple filters

Comment: @sniels Wouldn't using `ng-if` mean that `<td>` elements evaluating to `FALSE` will not show? I still want all my `<td>` elements to show, but apply a filter to some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to recreate your problem and solved it with `ng-if`.
There seems to be a function in the angular namespace to check every type like date, string, number, which I injected into the view through the scope.
Also notice I used the `ng-repeat="(key, value) in ..."` assuming that you are iterating over an object, [source](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.19/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="RootController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in attr_array">
      <td><b>{{key}}</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span ng-if="isDate(value)">{{value | date: 'MMM d, y'}}</span>
        <span ng-if="isNumber(value)">{{value | number: 4}}</span>
        <span ng-if="isString(value)">{{value | uppercase}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('RootController', function($scope) {
        $scope.isDate = angular.isDate;
        $scope.isNumber = angular.isNumber;
        $scope.isString = angular.isString;
        $scope.attr_array = {
          date: new Date(),
          str: "hello",
          nm: 50.2
        };
      });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is no simple and elegant way to do it. You can't have dynamic filter so you choices are in prefered to less preferred order:

- Preformat date fields dynamically in controller
- Use ngIf/ngShow switches
- Write custom filter that will apply another filter base on some configuration.

Here is an example of the custom filter approach:

```js
angular.module('demo', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.attr_array = [
    {key: 'created', value: new Date, filter: ['date', 'MMM d, y']},
    {key: 'name', value: 'Thomas Mann', filter: 'uppercase'},
    {key: 'price', value: 1233.45, filter: 'number'},
    {key: 'description', value: 'Some long string', filter: ['limitTo', 10] }
  ]
})

.filter('transform', function($filter) {
  return function(value, filter) {
    var filterData = [].concat(filter);
    filterData.splice(1, 0, value);
    return $filter(filterData.shift()).apply(this, filterData);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>

<table ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in attr_array">
    <td><b>{{ x.key }}</b>
    </td>
    <td>{{ x.value | transform:x.filter }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```